# Input-Output error when reading directory

Tags: curl, libcurl, curlftpfs

I have a problem with reading folders/files of a curlftpfs-mounted folder:
The server is using **FTPES with explicit TLS/SSL** and I have only reading permissions on it.

My system is using Mint15 (Ubuntu 13.04), curlftpfs 0.9.2, libcurl 7.29.0, fuse 2.9

My used command is:

```
curlftpfs -r -v -o ssl_control,cacert=~/serverzertifikat.pem,no_verify_peer,allow_other,tlsv1 username:password@host.com:990/efz_out ~/mount
```

This produces the following output:

> Couldn't find host hostname.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
>   About to connect() to hostname.com port 990 (#0)
>      Trying X.X.X.X...
>   Connected to hostname.com (X.X.X.X) port 990 (#0)
>   SOME HOST INFORMATIONS
>   AUTH SSL
>   234 Proceed with negotiation.
>   error reading ca cert file ~/serverzertifikat.pem (Error while reading file.)
>   server certificate verification SKIPPED
>   compression: NULL
>   cipher: AES-128-CBC
>   MAC: SHA1
>   USER username
>   331 Please specify the password.
>   PASS password
>   230 Login successful.
>   PBSZ 0
>   200 PBSZ set to 0.
>   PROT C
>   200 PROT now Clear.
>   PWD
>   257 "/"
>   Entry path is '/'
>   CWD efz_out
>   250 Directory successfully changed.
>   Remembering we are in dir "efz_out/"
>   Connection #0 to host hostname.com left intact

When I now go into my mounted directory and want to list all files with

```
ls -al
```

I get the following error message:

> ls: reading directory .: Input/output error
>   total 0

I already googled a long time and tried a lot of different options, but none of them changed sth.

Maybe one of you has experience with it and can help me?

My opinion is, that the problem has to do with FTPES (I found some post, where other users had the same problem with their servers, but that couldn't help me, because the used the option: no_verify_hostname, which isn't actually no more supported because of security issues)

Answer (score 4):

We have recently faced the same issue and found out that the passive mode of the FTP server has been disabled. In order to tell curlftpfs to connect in active mode, run with `-o ftp_port=-` option.

`$> curlftpfs -o user=<username>:<password>,ftp_port=- ftp://<FTP_IP> /mnt/ftp`.

Comment: Works for me. How do I set that option in the fstab instead than using the command line program ?

Answer (score 0):

Comment 12 here fixed it for me on RHEL 7
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1183409

Short version, run this first:
export NSS_STRICT_NOFORK=DISABLED